# How to deploy Node app to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment

I have an Angular app that I have on a server and loads the html page when the page loads. I have since made it a fullstack app by using node which entry point is server.js which holds the routes.

Locally, I run node server.js in a powershell cmd but I dont know how to do that on the remote server

How do I tell the server that this is now a node app and that it needs to initally run server.js instead of the angular's html page?

Comment: *node server.js* ?

Answer (score 1):

The command is node server.js. Alternatively you can download nodemon which restarts the server everytime the code is changed.

Comment: I use node server.js to run my app locally in windows powershell but how do I do that on the server?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: my server is hosted on aws

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html You need to set up node on aws and then run the server. Please follow the steps in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a Bitnami MEAN instance on the AWS if you are a starter. It has got complete stack with an Apache server to handle requests. Install nodemon and forever to keep the node process running.

[MEAN Stack Deployment Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/mean/)

Then follow this to deploy your custom application. [Here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/nodejs/#how-to-create-a-custom-nodejs-application)

In this setup Apache will face the external requests and proxy it to your node js application.